# Button Showing a Box

Tags: android

I am trying to make my Button displays a text when clicking on it. 
I will give you an example of what I meant : 
When clicking a button, a text will appear above the button and pointing to that button. 
How can this be done?

Comment: u have to make a custom design, or make an image of this shape with visibiity GONE, & make it visible on Click

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a `TextView` programmatically in the `onClick` event or add it in the xml, set its visibility to `gone` or `invisible` and change it in the `onClick` event

Comment: this must be a comment, & how will a textview point towards the button ?? There must be some image inside imageView

Comment: With [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int))

Comment: if u can, y didn't you show him 2 to 5 lines of code which can solve his issue.. (effort to gain repo)